# Javascript Templating with Django

Tags: javascript, django, templates

I'd really like to use a Javascript templating system together with Django. The syntax and style of Mustache.js (and it's derivatives) really sits well with me. The problem is the delimiter tag used by Mustache doesn't play nicely with the syntax of Django's templating system.

Is there any good way to use them together?

I have tried using [this verbatim snippet](https://gist.github.com/893408) to render the JS templates properly. The problem with that solution is I still sometimes need Django variables or URLs inside the JS.

I have also tried changing the delimiter for Mustache using

```
{{=[[ ]]=}}
```

However, that doesn't allow for using section tags, like {{#}}. The author has said he intends on removing that capability in future releases altogether.

Are there any template libraries for Javascript that follow closely to Mustache.js, but use different delimiters? Or is there another solution for changing the delimiters Mustache.js uses?

Answer (score 4):

I've used jquery's templating with django.  Ultimately I decided the best way is:

- put all the javascript into static javascript files and serve them up without any serverside processing
- in the django templates deliver all the html hooks (id's or classes) but no js.
- in the js use 'document.ready' plus jquery selectors to insert tags into the page and attach events
- if the js needs data then make an ajax call.

I softened on the last one and might embed data as a block of json into the django template, and perhaps also have a short js at the bottom of a template which do no more than set variables/parameters to instruct the js how to render the page - little clues from the server side telling it what to do.

Thus:

1. contention between the escape characters becomes a non-issue
2. you don't have to keep asking yourself "is this code running on the server or on the client" because you're not trying to write both at once into the one file
3. your javascript code is necessarily better structured and re-usable

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it would be extremely easy to [change Mustache's delimiters](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/b7cad83536b29f0640f5c35a97a8616975f3093f/mustache.js#L11), although configurable delimiters should be supported in my opinion.

If this is not acceptable to you, there are many other templating libraries out there such as [jquery-tmpl](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) and [underscore.template](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template).

Answer (score 0):

[EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/) is a pretty nice templating system. It uses `<% %>` tags.

Edit: [More templating libs](http://microjs.com/#templating)

Comment: EJS seems to be doing things backward to me. I'll give it a closer look though. Thanks for the tip on microjs.com!